# Decoding parameters in Google webapps

Tags: html, json, base64, decode

I'm trying to better understand the google web applications, the HTML source has JSON that has been encoded in some unknown way which i would like to decode. For example the below source contains parameter such as DpimGf, EP1ykd which makes no sense

```
view-source:https://contacts.google.com/
..window.WIZ_global_data = {"DpimGf":false,"EP1ykd":.....
```

So far i have tried the following

```
1. Decoded using the base64 decoder, but results are unprintable/not usable.
2. Decoded using poly-line encoding used in Google Maps.
3. Built an app from scratch to perform base64->binary->XOR->ASCII char and to shift the binary values up-to 7 places [inspired by poly-line algorithm]
```

Is there any documentation from google or known encoding for such formats.

Assumptions : I'm pretty sure that this encoding of some sort and not encryption, because

```
1) Length of the encrypted text dont match the common encryption algorithms 
2) There is some sort of pattern with value of the parameters,
   So good chance that its just encoded without any encryption.
   Because common encryption provides completely different strings each time.
3) There is a good chance that they may not decode, 
   because it might have a mapping at server side to a meaningful parameter.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using this http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/?results=cddb95fa500e7c1af427d005985260a7. try running the whole thing in this it might help